# considerations on dictionaries/hashsets with mutable elements

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset, mutable

I am a big fan of dictionaries and hashsets because they allow fast check for containedness and, in case of the dictionary, fast element access by key.

The downside of them is that they only work for (quasi-)immutable objects: Since they are based on hashing, we have to guarantee that the hash code (of the key for dictionaries, of the elements for hashsets) never changes, otherwise they will not find the elements any more.

But sometimes I need the benefits of dictionaries/hashsets and still be able to change the keys/elements in a way so that their hashcode changes as well. Example: I want to store 2d-points in a collection. 2d-points consist of two int values, and two 2d-points are equal if their int values are equal. I need to be able to change the values of the points, but I still need a fast way to check if a certain point is contained in the collection.

So I was thinking of a way to make it work. What would I need?

- Whenever I want to change the data of an element, I would need to 1. remove the element from the dictionary/set, 2. change the data, 3. add the element to the dictionary/set again. Then the hashcode and the bucket where the element is stored in would always be in sync.
- I would also need a mechanism to do this for all dictionaries/sets automatically. Otherwise, if I have 100 dictionaries/sets containing one element that is going to be changed, I would need to keep track of them and update each individually.

Here is some sample code to illustrate how I plan to tackle this for 2d-points and sets:

```
interface IChangeable<T>
{
    event EventHandler<T> OnStartChange; // must be run before changing data
    event EventHandler<T> OnEndChange;  // must be run after changing data
}

class Point : IChangeable<Point>
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }

    public event EventHandler<Point> OnStartChange;
    public event EventHandler<Point> OnEndChange;

    public int X
    {
        get => x;
        set
        {
            if (x.Equals(value)) // no change => no need to do anything
                return;

            OnStartChange?.Invoke(this, this); // remove current point from set
            x = value;
            OnEndChange?.Invoke(this, this); // add changed point to set
        }
    }

    public int Y { ... } // analogous to X

    public override int GetHashCode() { return x + 2 * y; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Point other = obj as Point;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return (x.Equals(other.x) && y.Equals(other.y));
    }
}

class MySet<T> : ISet<T> where T : class, IChangeable<T>
{
    HashSet<T> internalSet;

    public MySet() { internalSet = new HashSet<T>(); }

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        if (!internalSet.Add(item)) // if already contained, do nothing
            return false;

        item.OnStartChange += TakeOut; // else subscribe to data change events
        item.OnEndChange += PutIn;
        return true;
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        if (!internalSet.Remove(item)) // if not contained, do nothing
            return false;

        item.OnStartChange -= TakeOut; // else unsubscribe to data change events
        item.OnEndChange -= PutIn;
        return true;
    }

    public bool Contains(T item) { return internalSet.Contains(item); }

    private void TakeOut(object obj, T elem) { internalSet.Remove(elem); }

    private void PutIn(object obj, T elem) { internalSet.Add(elem); }

    ... // implement the rest of ISet<T> interface
}
```

So I would need to use `MySet` instead of a regular `HashSet`, and I would need to build setters utilizing the two events for each piece of data that I want to change (as long as that piece of data is incorporated into the `GetHashCode` or the `Equals` method).

My question is:

**Do you see any errors in my approach or any problems with this approach?**

- code readability/understandibility problems
- implementation problems
- performance problems
- correctness problems
- ...

It should be noted that changing the data is not going to happen very often. So I am convinced that the performance gain from being able to check containedness fast will outweight the performance hit from updating the set(s) after every data change.

Comment: I'd say that event-based approach seems like a bit of an overkill here. Why not simply use `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Point>` and check whether some certain point with x;y coordinates exists and if you'd need to change it - simply remove it and add a new one... It's not without a reason that in Winforms class Point is immutable (as well as KeyValuePair in Dictionary).

Comment: Unless you have a problem this is a question for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). To me such requirement is of an exotic kind. Dictionary have no problem with mutable values, only keys are the problem. But why would I want to mutate keys? They are not a part of data typically and are only used in conjunction with the dictionary, which means: delete entry with old key, change key, add new entry.

Comment: @Fabjan `Point` is just for illustration. My actual data has nothing to do with points, but it's not fit for a little code sample.

Comment: @Sinatr In my situation, I have objects where the key is actually part of the value (for such situations, .NET provides an abstract class called `KeyedCollection`, but I wanted to do it from scratch to find errors more easily). Usually the key is the name of the object, and I need to be able to rename objects.